# AngularJS: Returning to original page in single page application reloads JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, single-page-application

I am having a problem with my single page application reloading pre-loaded JS files, causing the web application to fail.

I am using AngularJS for a single page application, with a Rails 4 server side, which providers the API, and the template files for the SPA are kept in the rails' public directory.

The problem occurs only when I click the back button, when following links in the application, everything works fine. Say I started on the page /admin/users, if I were to visit /admin/sections, then visit /admin/users again, the /admin/users page will load fine. However clicking the back button twice, and returning to the original /admin/users page, everything is reloaded, the reloading of the JavaScript causes the single page application to crash, as the files are loaded twice.

This has been tried in html5mode set to true and false, the same problem occurs.

Rails is set up to send all /admin/* requests to /admin where angular then works out which template it needs to show by using the url.

(I will provide code samples if required)

Comment: Use angular router to handle all the client-side routing and extract your server API calls into a service that only runs once.

Comment: I am using $routeProvider for all the routing in the app, the only time rails is uses is to load up the skeleton single page application when the user first visits the site, Angular handles the rest. The only other thing Rails provides is the data in JSON format, otherwise it handles no html.